# Number of methods in a WCF service

Tags: wcf

Is it ok to have a 200 methods in a single WCF service? I can not avoid that it is just big service. Is it not a good practice and how to deal with it if it isn't ok?

Comment: It is **not** OK and you can avoid it.

Comment: It requires disciplined requirements gathering and design.

Comment: Without knowing more about your service, it's very hard to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any problem in having 200 methods in a service, but seems to me a bad design.

You can categorize on any relevant thing to keep in different class. Is it like all the 200 methods are availabe to everybody and in one go and you dont want to put some SOC ?

Comment: how will I separate it? by adding few more services?

Comment: Yes.  Group related methods together in individual services.  For example, if you have a grocery store you might have an order service, a stock/inventory service, a customer service, an employee service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of service composition. 200 service operations = high granularity. What are your operation names? I'm guessing, but I bet they are like:

- InsertTypeA (TypeA typeA)
- InsertTypeB (TypeB typeB)
- UpdateTypeA (TypeA oldTypeA, TypeA newTypeA)
- DeleteTypeB (int typeBId)
- etc..

What you need to think about is what *business events* is the service facilitating? So a business event would be something like:

- Product added to catalogue
- Account merged with child account
- Invoice issued to customer
- etc

So your service operations should reflect your business events:

- AddProductToCatalogue (int productId, int catalogueId)
- MergeAccounts (int accountId, int childAccountId)
- IssueInvoice (int customerId)
- etc

By focusing on business events you can make your service operations much higher level and require fewer of them. How many business events are performed by your typical application? Three? Four? This is how many service operations you should be exposing.